# Checked Checkbox showing at top on React Filter Search

Tags: reactjs

I Created a Filterable Search box using "react-filter-search" npm module.
Then I added a checkbox to every item in search list. after i check the checkbox in any item in a list and then search for any item, the checkbox i checked comes to the top and stays on first item in list.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the question is?...

Comment: We are not gonna re-implement what you are describing just to give you an answer, however if you post your code, we can tell you what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Working fine:

[image]

Working Not fine:

[image]

So check your Key. Your key should get from array if you use by default index then it will not give expected output.